# Zend SQL is dropping my where criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, where-clause

Why is this query dropping the criteria?  It does not seem to matter if I use a variable or hardkey a value ('97225') after the coma. Thank you for the insight.

```
$pro_zip = '97224';

Zend PHP:
        $sql = new Sql($adapter);
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->from('pro_table')
            ->join(array('specialty' => 'pro_specialty_table'),
                    'specialty.pro_id = pro_table.pro_id')
            ->join(array('specialty_name' => 'specialty_name_table'),
                    'specialty_name.specialty_name_id = specialty.speciality_name_id')
           ->where('pro_table.pro_zip = ?',$pro_zip);
```

SQL Output:

```
    SELECT `pro_table`.*, `specialty`.*, `specialty_name`.* FROM `pro_table` 
INNER JOIN `pro_specialty_table` AS `specialty` ON `specialty`.`pro_id` = `pro_table`.`pro_id` 
INNER JOIN `specialty_name_table` AS `specialty_name` ON `specialty_name`.`specialty_name_id` = `specialty`.`speciality_name_id`
 WHERE pro_table.pro_zip = ''
```

Comment: `var_dump($pro_zip);` right before your `$select`

Comment: ummm... `var_dump($pro_zip);` right **after** your `$select`?

Comment: What if you put `pro_table.pro_zip = 42` to where, with hardcoded value? Will it change anything?

Comment: ->where('pro_table.pro_zip=97224'); this works.   -   >where('pro_table.pro_zip=$pro_zip'); this does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this looks like ZF2, I think you want:

```
->where(array('pro_table.pro_zip' => $pro_zip));
```